# How to bind parent's size to its child's size and vice versa in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have this predefined class *template* which is initialized on application `start` method (basically, it is not defined by the user by default). It serves as the `root` container, and is already attached to a scene and the primary stage. The user can only specify the main `content` to one of its method which requires a `Node` as param, well, since the main content won't be resized along with the window, I'd like to bind its size to the `root` if it is a `resizable` node, and vice versa (if the content's size was changed so as the root/window).

Right now, all I can think of is check if the node is an `instanceof` a `Region` (which is the most common layout container), but there are also nodes that is `resizable` which does not extends from it like `WebView`. In that case, I don't want to specify them one by one. Is there a more convenient way?

---

## EDIT

Here's how I did it. Both works when the content's size is specified by default as well as when the window is resized manually:

```
public class Template extends Region {

  /**
   * Sets the main content.
   */
  private Node content;
  public void addContent(Node content) {
    if (this.content != null) {
      getChildren().remove(this.content);
    }
    if (content!= null) {
      getChildren().add(content);

      // Bind size to the content if it is a resizable node.
      if (content instanceof Region) {
        prefWidthProperty().bind(((Region) content).widthProperty());
        prefHeightProperty().bind(((Region) content).heightProperty());
        // Min and max size as well...
      } else if (content instanceof WebView) {
        prefWidthProperty().bind(((WebView) content).widthProperty());
        prefHeightProperty().bind(((WebView) content).heightProperty());
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
  public void getContent() {
    return content;
  }

  @Override
  protected void layoutChildren() {
    super.layoutChildren();
    final Node content = getContent();

    // Layout containers automatically fill the entire root (or if it is a resizable node like WebView)
    if (content instanceof Region || content instanceof WebView) {
      content.resize(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide please some related code which would clearly describe the hierarchy of the JavaFX nodes.

Comment: @Nikolas The `root` was simply the parent and the `child` was the main content. The method I mentioned is the way to add this `child` as its children.

Comment: `Node.isResizable`? Binding the size of the root should fail though, since the size of the root of a scene is determined by the scene size...

Comment: @fabian Uhm, yes. But as long as the window is resized, the root will be resized as well right? Then it's fine for me. I mean, not directly binding the size to the `root` (or the parent) but to the window is fine.